# How to convert a string containing an array into a list<ushort> ?

Tags: c#

For example there is a 
string str = "[2,3,4,5]"
How to convert this array of type string into a list where I can get each element in the list of type ushort? 
The string gets the value "[2,3,4,5]" from ruby script.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
List<ushort> myUshorts = new List<ushort>("[200,3,4,5]".Trim('[', ']').Split(',').Select(ushort.Parse));
```

if you know that's exactly how the output will be.

Answer (score 1):

Using linq you could do it like

```
var numbers = str.Where(y=>Char.IsDigit(y)).Select(p=>UInt16.Parse(p.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Comment: That gives me a char[] array. But I wanted an array of type ushort.

Comment: @HarryYerramsetty no. the updated code will give you an uint16[]

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite simple. All you need to do is write a method that parses the string and splits it up. Here is an basic example with **NO** error checking or optimizations. The naming convention is purely for your understanding purposes.

```
List <ushort> ConvertToUShortList (string arrayText)
{
    var result = new List<ushort> ();
    var bracketsRemoved = arrayText.Replace ("[", "").Replace ("]", "");
    var numbersSplit = bracketsRemoved.Split ( new string[] {","}, System.StringSplitOptions.None);

    foreach (var number in numbersSplit)
    {
        result.Add (ushort.Parse (number));
    }

    return result;
}
```

I shouldn't need to explain anything in this method due to the names I have given things. If you don't understand anything, let me know and I'll clarify it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Another method (more checks):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var str = "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]";

        var x = FromRubyArray(str);

        Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", x));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static List<ushort> FromRubyArray(string stra)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stra)) return new List<ushort>();
        stra = stra.Trim();
        stra = stra.Trim('[', ']');

        return stra                
            .Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(s => Convert.ToUInt16(s))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this string is using a "Json-like" format, you can use this code:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var array = serializer.Deserialize<ushort[]>("[2,3,4,5]");
```

You just need to reference the System.Web.Extensions assembly

Answer (score 1):

Another elegant way using Newtonsoft's Json.net (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
            var ushortArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ushort>>(myString);
```